# Search in 2D list using python to find x,y position

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-2.7, search

I have 2D list and I need to search for the index of an element. As I am begineer to programming I used the following function:

```
def in_list(c):
    for i in xrange(0,no_classes):
        if c in classes[i]:
            return i;

    return -1
```

Here classes is a 2D list and no_classes denotes the number of classes i.e the 1st dimesntion of the list. -1 is returned when c is not in the araray. Is there any I can optimize the search?

Comment: you can optimize it if you will use an appropriate data structure, like set, or if you sort your lists beforehand, otherwise it O(N^2) algorithm and you cannot do it faster

Comment: @Roman Park: can you please give some hints about optimizing this?

Comment: do you have duplicates in your lists? does order of element matters?

Comment: no duplicates...and order really doesnt matter

Comment: This is a good question, but I think it would be better in the code review stack exchange.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to define `no_classes` yourself. Use `enumerate()`:

```
def in_list(c, classes):
    for i, sublist in enumerate(classes):
        if c in sublist:
            return i
    return -1
```

Comment: How to proceed in case of multiple occurrences of the same element?

Comment: Figured it out, you just dont need to return the moment you encounter the first occurence

Answer (score 1):

Use list.index(item)

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4,5]]

def in_list(item,L):
    for i in L:
        if item in i:
            return L.index(i)
    return -1

print in_list(3,a)
# prints 1
```

Comment: you should add try except if you want to use index - see docs - `Return the index in the list of the first item whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item.` http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: It's not possible that there will be error here because i is certainly within the list since it is part of the list which we iterate over. No need for try except here.

Comment: oops, didn't see that, please edit the answer somehow so I could unvote my -1

Comment: no problem you can simply press down error again this should undo the downvote.

Comment: it's not possible to unvote after certain period of time :( unless answer is edited

Answer (score 1):

if order doesn't matter and you have no duplicates in your data, I suggest to turn you 2D list into list of sets:

```
>>> l = [[1, 2, 4], [6, 7, 8], [9, 5, 10]]
>>> l = [set(x) for x in l]
>>> l
[set([1, 2, 4]), set([8, 6, 7]), set([9, 10, 5])]
```

After that, your original function will work faster, because search of element in set is constant (while search of element in list is linear), so you algorithm becomes O(N) and not O(N^2).

Note that you should not do this in your function or it would be converted each time function is called.

Answer (score 1):

If your "2D" list is rectangular (same number of columns for each line), you should convert it to a `numpy.ndarray` and use numpy functionalities to do the search. For an array of integers, you can use `==` for comparison. For an array of float numbers, you should use `np.isclose` instead:

```
a = np.array(c, dtype=int)
i,j = np.where(a == element)
```

or

```
a = np.array(c, dtype=float)
i,j = np.where(np.isclose(a, element))
```

such that `i` and `j` contain the line and column indices, respectively.

Example:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2],
              [3, 4],
              [2, 6]], dtype=float)
i, j = np.where(np.isclose(a, 2))
print(i)
#array([0, 2])
print(j)
#array([1, 0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

using list comprehension: (2D list to 1D)

```
a = [[1,22],[333,55555,6666666]]
d1 = [x for b in a for x in b]
print(d1)
```